# Why is this Cyclic sort not working in Java

Tags: java, sorting, cycle-sort

I made a simple cyclic sort program whose code is given below

Code 1:

```
static void cyclicSort(int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[arr[i] - 1]) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[arr[i] - 1];
            arr[arr[i] - 1] = temp;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

But the program does not work when I call this function and try to print the sorted array.

It does not give an error. There is simply no output.

But when I use the following code the program works.

Code 2:

```
static void cyclicSort(int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        int correct = arr[i] - 1;
        if (arr[i] != arr[correct]) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[correct];
            arr[correct] = temp;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference between code 1 and code 2 is that in code 2 I have created a new variable `correct`, which is equal to `arr[i] - 1` and in CODE 1 I have directly used `arr[i] - 1`.

I have rechecked the code a number of times and this is the only difference, so why is it that the code is not working in code 1?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the value of `arr[i] - 1` changes when you do `arr[i] = arr[arr[i] - 1];`. This means that on the next line, you are actually accessing a different index.

Introducing the `correct`-variable fixes this issue, because the value of the variable will not change when you mutate `arr[i]`.